# Problem with Setting Vuex State Property to an Object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I have the following pattern inside one of my store modules for Vuex. (This is not my actual code, but it shows the same behaviour):

```
const state = () => ({
  userId: 'foo',
  now: new Date()
  //And so on
})

const getters = {
   getUserId: (state, getters) => state.userId,
   getDate: (state, getters) => state.now.toISOString()
}
```

If I try to do `this.$store.getters['moduleFoo/getUserId']` in a page or component after setting user id with an action or manually, it works fine.

But `this.$store.getters['moduleFoo/getDate']` is undefined.

Why is this and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to set the date in the store? Trying to understand what you want to achieve to find an optimal solution.

Comment: No not really. It is a different type of object which represents user credentials. But the pattern is the same.  I don't really want to add all the properties from that object to the store directly, because that is too messy to handle. I would rather have a single object set in the store. The problem is the same either way. The getter for that object is undefined for some reason.

Comment: Using the example that you gave, try using this.$store.moduleName.now.toISOString()

Comment: That works but it is not ideal. It won't work with `mapGetters()` or  with this.$store.getters['moduleName'] approach.